# Ansible: How to obtain the current inventory location

Tags: ansible

I have a number of Ansible environments:

```
environments
  dev
    hosts
    group_vars/
  prod
    hosts
    group_vars/
```

and I need to create a "setup" playbook that would copy some files in the  `group_vars` of the environment that I use.

e.g. `ansible-playbook -i environments/dev setup.yml --extra-vars="target=server1"`

should copy a file from the **server1** to **environments/dev**

Currently I have in tasks:

```
 tasks:
 - name: Copy SSL certificate
   fetch:
      src: /path/to/file.crt
      dest: <inventoty_path>
      flat: yes
```

but I don't know what to use for `<inventory_path>`.

Is there a variable where the current inventory absolute path is set? Or a way to obtain it (without setting an extra variable for this) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are a couple of "special variables":

- `ansible_inventory_sources`
- `inventory_dir`
- `inventory_file`

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/special_variables.html

There is also a configuration option `inventory`:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/intro_configuration.html#inventory

You can also set an environment variable:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.4/config.html#envvar-ANSIBLE_INVENTORY

Answer (score 1):

There is a magic variable `inventory_dir` which return a path to current inventory file. Doc: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts